# An online version of Tattva Bindu of Vacapati Misra

Tags: scripture, advaita

I am interested in the works of Vacapati Misra I am wondering if I can get a free, english translation of his work Tattva Bindu where he summarizes his reasoning.

Comment: It doesn't have an eng. translation till now afaik.

Comment: @Bingming oh okay I need some help I cannot focus on something. Can you please chat.

Comment: I am sorry, I can't give any personal help, and I usually don't chat here.

Comment: @Bingming all good I want you to pick a dharmashastra a beginner with a good commentary and I will read from page 1 to end, otherwise I will be drifting from one scripture to another and distress which follow.

Comment: You can pick up Yājñavalkya smṛti or Manusmṛti, former with comm. Mitākṣarā (by Vijñāneśvara) and the latter with Manubhāṣya (by Medhātithi). Both are pretty expansive.

Comment: @Bingming your word is my command

Comment: There is nothing about command, you asked for recommendations of dharmaśāstras, I gave two of them, which are pretty famous and well known. There are many other dharmaśāstras too.

Comment: @Bingming ofc, but I just cannot focus.

Comment: I am choosing to read Yajnavalkya and Narayaniya